# How to Tweak Office 2016 Theme Colors?

Tags: microsoft-office, themes

Just started using the 2016 Office Black theme.  I love it, except that the snooze text is light grey on white, which is not readable...  Any idea how to change it to black?

[image: Bad Snooze Text Color]